# Return a line of text with the file.readline() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a file name 'itspython.txt' and below is the input:

> *"My name is Srivatsasa Janaswamy. I am currently working at Accenture Bangalore.  I am looking for better opportunities blah blah blahhhhh I
>   am writing to stack overflow"*

On multiple websites, **it has been given that `readline(3)` should print the 3rd line from the file.**

I have given `print(file.readline(3))` as a command.

The output, when I execute this statement.

> **My**

Below is the three line program:

```
f=open("itspython.txt",'r')
con=f.readline(3)
print(con)
```

Comment: Even though the content of the file mentioned in this post is of 2 lines, but in actual note pad. its 3 line of input content

Comment: `.readline` only reads one line at a time each time... you don't specify an argument to it to read the nth line... are you perhaps getting mixed up with the `readline` module instead?

Comment: "its been given that readline(3) should print 3rd line from the file" - where the heck did you get that idea?

Comment: check the documents first. fp.readline reads the next line. fp.readlines  will read all the line. fp.readlines()[3]  will read the 3rd line if available, or exception. but you need to check a lot of stuffs for correctness

Comment: @Nipun `[3]` will be the 4th line :)

Comment: `f.readline()` always reads from the next available line. Without an argument, it returns until the next newline character or end of file, whichever comes first. With an argument *n*, it will also stop reading after *n* bytes, even if a newline or EOF hasn't yet been seen.

Comment: @JonClements yes :)

Comment: @user2357112 its been given in this link :http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Comment: @srivatsasa: That source is terrible and you should stop using it. The `readline` thing is far from the only error.

Comment: @NipunTalukdar Thanks f.readlines()[n] worked out. So if f.readline() gives out one line at time, what is difference between f.read(1) and f.readline(1) -> These will give same result?

Comment: @JonClements :Thanks Jon

Comment: @user2357112 : yes it seems to be true :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`readline(3)` will only print the first 3 bytes of the first line.

`readlines()[2]` will create a list of all the lines in your document and will then give you the third one (Indexing starts from 0).

Comment: Mind you, a better solution is not to read an arbitrary number of lines when you only need one. `next(itertools.islice(f, 2, None))`, while longer to type, only reads the first three lines, returns the third, and leaves the rest of the file unread, rather than creating a potentially huge `list` of all the lines of the file at once to get a single line.